# problems to validate information in jwt

Tags: angular, spring, spring-security, jwt

How to perform data authentication with already done data. Using jwt to compare that data to validate information.
I have a spring app with springboot security library I am validating in JWT with angular and I need to read plain text files that is in mysql database how do I do to validate the information.
When the user logs in it validates with the info from the database.

```
login(): void {
    console.log(this.usuario);
    if (this.usuario.username == null || this.usuario.password == null) {
      swal('Error Login', 'Username o password vacías!', 'error');
      return;
    }

    this.authService.login(this.usuario).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);

      this.authService.guardarUsuario(response.access_token);
      this.authService.guardarToken(response.access_token);
      let usuario = this.authService.usuario;
      this.router.navigate(['/clientes']);
      swal('Login', `Hola ${usuario.username}, has iniciado sesión con éxito!`, 'success');
    }, err => {
      if (err.status == 400) {
        swal('Error Login', 'Usuario o clave incorrectas!', 'error');
      }
    }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Reading your question is not really clear what you are trying to solve. Your code is related with the `login` action but you mention `Using jwt to compare that data to validate information`, what are you trying to do? In the answer of @JuanBerzosaTejero, he has thought your problem is related with how to send `JWT token` in every "after login" request. So, the question is still the same, what is the specific use case you are trying to solve?

Comment: I agree with @doctore

Answer (score 0):

In order to get help, you should give more info...

But, basically, you need an **interceptor**, which for every http call, insert this in the head:

```
 setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          }
```

P.S: Because of your code variables names, I guees you speak Spanish, so this guide will help you:
https://medium.com/@insomniocode/angular-autenticaci%C3%B3n-usando-interceptors-a26c167270f4